# Is the Inscribed Garment Box only available for Neverwinter on PC?

Tags: xbox-one, neverwinter

I would like to purchase some leveling equipment that scales in Neverwinter.  According to the [Neverwinter Wiki, the Inscribed Garment Box](http://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Inscribed_Garment_Box) is the item I should get.  I am playing Neverwinter on my Xbox One and cannot locate the item in the Zen Market.   **Is this scaling gear only available on PC?**

[I have seen their press release under PC, but it doesn't mention availability.](http://www.arcgames.com/en/games/neverwinter/news/detail/9064183-now-available%3A-inscribed-garment-box)

I have also seen the Heirloom Pack, which provides equipment for every 5 levels from 5-50 but I would like the additional 10 levels covered and the bonus XP.

I tweeted at their support looking for some direction, but haven't heard a reply yet.

Any Ideas?